# Visual Studio 2010 - Function not inlined - Why?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio-2010, inline

I have a generic function calculating the inner product:

```
template < typename _A >
    inline typename _A::value_type innerProduct( const          _A&             A,
                                                 const typename _A::index_type& row0,
                                                 const typename _A::index_type& row1,
                                                 const typename _A::index_type& col,
                                                 const typename _A::size_type&  n )
    {
        typedef typename _A::value_type value_type;
        typedef typename _A::index_type index_type;

        value_type sum = value_type( );

        for( index_type i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        {
            sum += A( row0, i ) * A( row1, i );
        }

        return sum;
}
```

While calculating the cholesky decomposition I call the function multiple times. Because the overhead for the function call is large (~11%!) it shall be avoided. In my simple world I thought that the function is so small that the compiler will inline it. I checked the compiler options multiple times but I think they are fine. I use e.g. /Ox /O2 /Ob2 /GL.
I also checked that the function is visible to the compiler before function is called. But function is never inlined. The only working option is to define the function explicit with keyword __forceinline.

So what kind of options do I have to tell the compiler to inline the function ?
What are the criterions for the compiler if a function is inlined or not ?

Comment: Overhead is 11% in terms of space (code size) or execution time?  Doesn't execution time depend on `n`?  How big is `n` in your case?  How is the compiler supposed to know that `n` is very small while compiling this (is it a constant at the call site)?

Comment: Overhead is 11% for execution time when function is declared with __forceinline (=fast) or not (=slow). In both cases parameter n is always within the same (non constant) range.

Comment: Compilers usually don't inline functions with statements such as `for` and `while`. If `n` is always a constant in call-site, you could use it as a template parameter and turn your function recursive (it does inline recursive function in this case because the template parameter changes).

Answer (score 2):

The specific reasons why a function might not be inlined when the `inline` keyword aren't documented by Microsoft. (The closest I can find is the documentation for [compiler warning C4710](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd3056cz(v=vs.100).aspx).) The `inline` keyword is only a hint, and the compiler uses heuristics to determine whether inlining is a worthwhile optimization. There are various cases where inlining can hurt performance, for example if it increases register pressure.

You've already discovered the solution to this problem: use the `__forceinline` keyword to tell the compiler you know better. To make it conditional at the call site, create two versions of the `innerProduct` function, one with `__forceinline` and one without. It looks like you can implement the later by calling the former. Something like:

```
__forceinline value_type innerProduct_forceinline(...) {
    ...
    return sum;
}

inline value_type innerProduct(...) {
    return innerProduct_forceinline(...);
}
```

Comment: Thx for your feedback. The reason for avoiding the __forceinline keyword is that the function is very generic and may be used within different projects. So I don´t know if it makes sense to inline the function everytime.

Comment: Create two versions of the function, one with `__forceinline` and one without? You might be able to call the `__forceinline` version from the non- version to avoid having to implement it twice.

Comment: Uh oh yes...great and simple idea :) I think this solves the issue *facepalm